# $(window).scrollTop tied to $(window).scroll() event acting oddly

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, scroll

I'm trying to trigger a function when the window is scrolled more than a certain number of pixels.

Here's my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if( $(this).scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
    someFunction();
  } else {
    someOtherFunction();
  }
});
```

It kinda works, but there's either a delay of around 2-4 seconds after scrolling before the function(s) are fired or else the functions aren't triggered at all.

Tried it out in Safari / Chrome. Don't know if that helps or not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine and works for me.

As Wolfram says, it's rarely a good idea to attach handlers directly to the scroll event, as this fires a *lot* and can bring the user's system to a crawl.

I'd recommend using [Ben Alman's jquery throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

Comment: Ben's plugin looks like a really good solution - I'll check it out. Cheers ^R

Comment: Yup, using the plugin has solved the issue. I guess the event was firing a gazillion times and that's what was causing the problem. Thanks for the help @Deebster!

Comment: Nice link, and Ben's first usage example is almost exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It works using jQuery 1.6.1 + mousewheel / scrollbar in Chrome15/Safari5.1/FF7 on OSX. What are you doing in those two functions? For testing, I put a simple alert() in `someFunction` and nothing in `someOtherFunction`.

Remember that one of those functions is executed every time the scroll-event fires unless you stop it once it was called... e.g. someFunction is called a lot after you scrolled below the 100px line.

John Resig: [It's a very, very, bad idea to attach handlers to the window scroll event.](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/)

Comment: Very good point about the function being fired so many times. Maybe I can wrap it up in a boolean or something...

Answer (score 0):

If you're scolling by holding in the click-button instead of using the scroll wheel, I believe the event won't fire until you release the click-button.

Have you considered running a loop that checks the `scrollTop` instead?

**EDIT:**
I just check an old project of mine using window scroll event, and it runs perfect with the same event.

I asume you have this script of yours wrapped inside:

```
$(function() {
   // code
});
```